# Navigating between components reloads all components in navigator routes

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I've read somewhere that when you use any navigator from the `react-navigation` package and if you implement redux; every component in the navigators' routes will be reloaded (i.e `componentWillRecieveProps`)

However, I've got two pages where the user can login

```
export const MainScreenTabNavigator = TabNavigator({
    Start: {
        screen: Start,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Start',
        },
    },
},{
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#222',
        labelStyle: {
            color: '#ddd',
        },
        style: { backgroundColor: '#333' },
    }
});

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: MainScreenTabNavigator, // Nested tab navigator
    },
    Login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Aanmelden',
        }
    },
    Camera: {
        screen: AppCamera,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Camera',
        }
    }

}, {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

The login screen is initially shown to the user. It has a form where the user can enter it's credentials manually and a button that navigates to the camera where the user can scan a QR code with login credentials.

In both cases the user dispatches a login action.
Both the login page and the camera page listen to the same prop changes:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.account.loginSuccess) {
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Start' }));
    } else {
        if (nextProps.account.loginError) {
            Toast.showLongBottom(nextProps.loginError);
        }
    }
    this.setState({spinnerVisible: false});
}
```

The app successfully navigates to 'Start' but when it does both the Login and Camera page are reloaded, causing an infinite loop into `componentWillReceiveProps` and infinitely navigates to 'Start' over and over again.

This is my navigation reducer:

```
function nav(state = initialNavState, action) {
    const nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);

    // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
    return nextState || state;
}
```

What can I do to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

As a temporary solution I introduced another boolean into the nav state:

```
function nav(state = initialNavState, action) {
    let nextState = null;

    if (action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' && action.routeName === 'Start') {
        nextState = {...AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state), authenticated: true};
    } else {
        nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    }

    // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
    return nextState || state;
}
```

I use `authenticated` to check if the login or camera component should navigate to start after logging in.

It works but it still feels like I'm missing something.